# Is possible to use finish() in to return in previous activities like C>B>A?

Tags: java, android

Technically I have a `MainActivity` "A" then then I'll go to next activity which is activity "B" then there is the other activity which is Activity "C"

But when I use finish, the activity B and C returns to each other instead backing to the main activity

Comment: post your activity calling code

Comment: Where to use finish method? Activity C?

Comment: dont use finish it will backstack on back pressed.

Comment: just call A intent in side finish() method of B or C classes if you want to go back to A class directly.but if you are using toolbar back button it will automatically take you to previous initial classes  .

Comment: call finish() while calling an activity through Intent

Comment: i want to use finish because in the activity A and B, i use JSON, so i don't want to load that list anymore,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you route from Activity A to B then c, and you pressing back from C to B and A. You don't need to use **finish()** anywhere. Because android maintain stack for back button. It automatically push all activities and pop activities when back.

Refer this : https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Comment: i want to use finish because in the activity A and B, i use JSON, so i don't want to load that list anymore, instead i must retain it in order not to load the list anymore, what method do you recommend

Comment: Try without using finish

Comment: Ok, i found the solution Thanks @SANAT i just remove startActivity() then i put addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); finish();

Answer (score 0):

The loading of JSON data part should be done in onCreate() method,because you dont want to re-load the data.override the onbackpressed() method of activity on the some action (like button click) of the A and B activity Or use finish.